# Getting the total using footerCall, error occurred in reduce()

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I'm using footerCallback with the editor and I'm getting the error: **Reduce of empty array with no initial value.**

I'm just trying to add a total of column 6 to the footer using the example.
I have tried this one.

```
 $("#exampleGrid").DataTable({
       var total =  api
                    .column(6)
                    .data()
                    .reduce()
    });
```

Comment: It would help if `api` is explained

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am just manage by this way.

```
var total = "";
if (api.column(6).data().length > 0) {
      total = api.column(6)
              .data()
              .reduce(function (a, b) {
               return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
               });
            }
else 
{
   total = 0;
}
```